Properties of determinants in Isabelle
I would like to use the facts that $\det AB=\det A \det B$ and $\det A = \det A^t$ to prove that $\det AA^t = (\det A)^2$ in Isabelle. Is there a fast way to do this without doing this from scratch?

You don't have to do this from scratch. The facts in HOL-Analysis.Determinants and related theories suffice.
Your first fact, $\det AB=\det A \det B$, is proposition Determinants.det_mul, which reads det (?A ** ?B) = det ?A * det ?B.
Your second fact, $\det A = \det A^t$, is called Determinants.det_transpose, reading det (Finite_Cartesian_Product.transpose ?A) = det ?A.
Mixing in some detail on the formulation of powers, one gets:
theory Scratch
  imports "HOL-Analysis.Determinants"
begin

lemma
  shows ‹det (A ** transpose A) = det A ^ 2›
  using det_mul det_transpose
  unfolding power2_eq_square
  by metis

sledgehammer has also told me that the simplifier is almost ready to prove your goal directly. It proposed the following proof:
lemma
  shows ‹det (A ** transpose A) = det A ^ 2›
  by (simp add: det_mul power2_eq_square)


Why does that section talk about Cartesian product? The ** seems to mean this.

@CraigFeinstein: ** is the syntax for matrix_matrix_mult, not for Cartesian products. But it's part of the scope/theory called HOL-Analysis.Finite_Cartesian_Product. All basic matrix defs can be found there. The background is that vectors are understood through finite (Cartesian) product types. A specific $n$-dimensional vector over say $\mathbb R$ is a member of the Cartesian $n$-product $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \ldots \times \mathbb R$. Matrices are vectors of vectors.

Thank you, good to know. I was also able to figure this all out by using another directory called Jordan_Normal_Form.

Sledgehammer was a big help.
